# Can invalid signature errors ever trigger at runtime if code has been statically checked by Sorbet?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I was looking through the list of Sorbet runtime errors [from the docs](https://sorbet.org/docs/tconfiguration). It seems to me that "Errors from invalid sig procs" and "Errors from invalid sigs" would be caught by the Sorbet type checker. If your code passes Sorbet's static checks, is it guaranteed that those runtime errors would never occur?

Comment: checks not happening and errors not happening is two different things. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: I'm asking whether the errors could happen, if the checks have happened and the code passes the checks.

Those errors seem to be related to malformed signatures which I would expect the checker to catch. For example in "errors from invalid sig procs" it says it will throw if you forget a `.returns()`. But if you forget that, `srb tc` gives you `Malformed sig: No return type specified. Specify one with .returns()`.

Basically I have some code that passes `srb tc` and I want to know whether sig_builder_error_handler or sig_validation_error_handler could ever be conceivably triggered in prod.

Answer (score 1):

### Basic answer

There are cases in which the static checks pass, but you'd get a runtime error. Consider the following:

```rb
# typed: strict

class A
  extend T::Sig
  sig {returns(Integer)}
  def foo; 0; end
end

class B < A
  sig {returns(String)}
  def foo; '0'; end
end

B.new.foo
```

Running this will end up in:

```
RuntimeError: Incompatible return type in signature for override of method `foo`
```

### Extra

You can avoid falling in this by making sure that you use `overridable` or `(:final)` ([docs](https://sorbet.org/docs/final)) in your signatures when appropriate.

```rb
class A
  extend T::Sig
  sig {overridable.returns(Integer)}
  def foo; 0; end

  sig (:final) {returns(Integer)}
  def bar; 0; end
end

class B < A
  sig {returns(String)} # this will fail static check, as it doesn't declare `override`
  def foo; '0'; end

  sig {returns(String)} # this will fail static check, as `bar` is `final`
  def bar; '0'; end
end
```